# Expression, phrase, or idiom that describes lazy team members/coworkers who work only on the least important and demanding tasks

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

I'm looking for a expression, idiom, or even proverb that could be used to describe situations like

1. In a work environment where it becomes apparent that coworkers set aside  duties that require prompt attention for other duties that are not time-sensitive or just ignore  them because they want other coworkers to attend to it.
2. Calling out a lazy quality you notice in individuals on a group project that take on the least demanding tasks.
3. Cherrypicking work duties that one likes to do again and again while leaving the latter for others to do. Typically the most difficult.

It is not perfect but what comes to my mind is:

> I'm not gonna play hot potato with you on [describes the work]"

It sounds a bit intense but

> While you focus on extinguishing the candle, I'll focus on the forest fire.

Comment: There are simply tons of words. One of them is slacker, another is shirker.

Comment: If you're looking for words that can act as constructive criticism, you'd first have to think it exists.

Comment: Mark, you're not pulling your weight here.